# When nesting components this.props.parent returns "undefined". How do I access a parents function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, I have:

```
<Page><Content1 /><Page>
<Page><Content2 /><Page>
```

Where Slide is:

```
  var Page = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {shouldHide: true};
    },

    hide: function() {
      this.state.shouldHide = true;
    },

    show: function() {
      this.state.shouldHide = false;
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className={this.state.shouldHide ? 'hidden' : ''}>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

I want to be able to call the `.hide()` and `.show()` functions from the child component. Is this possible?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement --- just pass the `hide` and `show` functions as props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use React.cloneElement to add props to your children in order to use your parent methods

```
render: function() {
        let children = React.cloneElement(this.props.children || <div/>,
                            {show: this.show, hide: this.hide });
        return (
          <div className={this.state.shouldHide ? 'hidden' : ''}>
             {children}
          </div>
);
```

And you shouldn't mutate your state directly, use **this.setState** instead.

this

```
hide: function() {
  this.state.shouldHide = true;
},

show: function() {
  this.state.shouldHide = false;
},
```

should be

```
hide: function() {
  this.setState({shouldHide: true});
},

show: function() {
  this.setState({shouldHide: false});
},
```